# Create a delegate from Methodinfo with generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

Based on this [old but very usefull article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) by the legendary Jon Skeet, I wrote a few methods to genereate Action Delegates from MethodInfos for faster invokations. But I ran into an issue, where I am unable to make any progress. See the example below:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public List<int> myList;

    public DataContainer()
    {
        myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void DoStuff<T>(this IList<T> items)
    {
    }
}

public class Example
{
    private Action<object> doStuffQuickly;

    public void Test()
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(DataContainer).GetField("myList");

        var doStuffMethod = typeof(ExtensionMethods).GetMethod("DoStuff", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var listType = typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(fieldInfo.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments);
        doStuffQuickly = QuickAccess.CreateWeakActionWithOneParam(doStuffMethod, listType);

        var data = new DataContainer();
        var list = fieldInfo.GetValue(data);

        doStuffQuickly(list);
    }
}

public static class QuickAccess
{
    private static MethodInfo _weak1ParamActionCreator;
    private static MethodInfo Weak1ParamActionCreator => _weak1ParamActionCreator
        ??= typeof(QuickAccess).GetMethod(nameof(CreateWeakExplicit1ParamAction), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public static Action<object> CreateWeakActionWithOneParam(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type paramType0 = null)
    {
        var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        paramType0 ??= parameters[0].ParameterType;
        var creationMethod = Weak1ParamActionCreator.MakeGenericMethod(paramType0);
        return (Action<object>)creationMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { methodInfo });
    }

    private static Action<object> CreateWeakExplicit1ParamAction<TValue>(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var action = CreateStrongExplicit1ParamAction<TValue>(methodInfo);
        return (object value) => action((TValue)value);
    }

    private static Action<TValue> CreateStrongExplicit1ParamAction<TValue>(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        //Debug.Log(methodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name + " <-> " + typeof(TValue).Name);
        //Debug.Log(PrintTypes(methodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments) + " <-> "
        //    + PrintTypes(typeof(TValue).GenericTypeArguments));
        return (Action<TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TValue>), methodInfo);
    }

    private static string PrintTypes(Type[] types)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", types.Select(t => t.Name));
    }
}
```

This fails with `ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible` when trying to create the delegate.
The commented logs print `` IList`1 <-> IList`1 `` and `T <-> Int32`, which made me think that maybe

```
var listType = typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(fieldInfo.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments);
```

should instead simply be

```
var listType = typeof(IList<>);
```

but that is causing an `InvalidOperationException: Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.`

I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly, `listType` would be a `IList<int>`, so `DoStuff` would be `DoStuff<IList<int>>`. I would expect it to be `DoStuff<int>`

So the correct version should be

```
var listItemType = fieldInfo.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments[0]; 
doStuffMethod = doStuffMethod.MakeGenericMethod(listItemType);
doStuffQuickly = QuickAccess.CreateWeakActionWithOneParam(doStuffMethod);
```

I would highly recommend running your code in a debugger and inspect your values in every step to confirm all your reflection types look like you expect. Reflection is difficult, so it is really useful to be able to confirm any assumptions.

Comment: Hey. Good catch, thank you. However I also noticed that I shouldn't pass the GenericTypeArguments into the ```CreateWeakActionWithOneParam``` method, but instead modify the methodInfo (doStuffMethod) itself. So the correct solution is: ```var listItemType = fieldInfo.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            doStuffMethod = doStuffMethod.MakeGenericMethod(listItemType);
            doStuffQuickly = QuickAccess.CreateWeakActionWithOneParam(doStuffMethod);```. If you update your answer accordingly, I'll mark it as correct.